# Is it bad to use concurrent.futures for the delayed tasks?

Tags: python

*(preamble: I use `python-telegram-bot` for running a Telegram bot which registers users' messages in Google Sheets. None of this is relevant for this question but may provide some context to understand the source of the troubles. The thing is that Google Sheets API does not allow too frequent access to the google sheets, so if many users try to write there, I need to process their requests with some delay).*

I know it is considered a very bad practice to use `threading` module to process tasks and avoid locking by GIL. But by the nature of my task, I receive a flow of requests from users, and I would like to process them with some delay (like from 1 to 10 seconds later than they were actually received). *(right now I use celery+redis to process delayed tasks but it looks like an overkill for me for such trivial thing as delayed execution, but I may be wrong)*.

So I wonder if I can use `concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor` (as it is explained for example here: https://idolstarastronomer.com/two-futures.html) or it will result in some kind of disaster promised by the most of people who warn against using `threading` in Python?

Here is purely hypothetical code that runs something with delay with `ProcessPoolExecutor`. Will it end up with a disaster under some conditions (too many delayed requests for instance)?

```py
import concurrent.futures
import time
import random


def register_with_delay():
    time.sleep(random.randint(0, 10))
    print('Im in the delayed registration')


def main():
    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
        futures = [executor.submit(register_with_delay) for _ in range(10)]
        for i in range(10):
            print('Im in the main loop')
            time.sleep(random.randint(0, 1))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: The best way to learn the answer is `testing`. Do you want to learn if it is going to fail under heavy load? Then write a test case for it and see the results.